# EventSource dynamic binding variable

Tags: angular

I try to update and display message from  variable updated into EventSource function:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
     const EventSource: any = window['EventSource'];
     const fx = new EventSource('/weather/update/');
     fx.onmessage = function (evt) {
          this.newMessage  = evt.data;
          console.log(this.newMessage);
     }
}
```

in template:

```html
<p>{{newMessage}}</p>
```

The received message always is empty, but in console i can see the new message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loosing context `this`. Try using arrow function in order to preserve `this`:

```
               like this     
                  \/
fx.onmessage = evt => {
   this.newMessage  = evt.data;
   console.log(this.newMessage);
}
```